# how to resolve TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list when try to convert a list of paths

Tags: python, pandas, path, shutil

I am new to Python, hope someone can help me with this question that I am currently stuck at. What I am trying to do is to move the files under a source folder to a destination folder after I read the data and combine them into one data frame. My script is attached here:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import psycopg2 as ps
import shutil

sub_folder = 'team project'

current_folder = os.getcwd()
working_folder = os.path.join(current_folder, sub_folder)

files = os.listdir(working_folder)

batch_files = [f for f in files if 'April 16' in f or 'April 23' in f]
batch_files = [ os.path.join(working_folder, f) for f in batch_files]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in batch_files:
    
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)
    
df

des_folder = 'destination'
destination = os.path.join(current_folder, des_folder)
dest = os.fspath(destination)
srt = os.fspath(batch_files)



dest = shutil.move(srt, dest)
```

when I try to run: srt = os.fspath(batch_files), I encountered the error message: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Could anyone kindly provide a solution to this? Appreciate it

Comment: As the error message says: `batch_files` is a list, it should be a string, bytes or os.PathLike object. I think you want to loop over `batch_files` and move the files (in this list) to your destination.

Answer (score 1):

do you want this?

```
for f in batch_files:  
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)
    
    #move everything below here into your for loop    
    df
    
    des_folder = 'destination'
    destination = os.path.join(current_folder, des_folder)
    dest = os.fspath(destination)
    srt = os.fspath(f) # remove the list and use 'f'
    
    dest = shutil.move(srt, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

As both folder `team_project` and `destination` are directly below the current folder I would refactor (rewrite) your code as follows:

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

current_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
working_folder = 'team_project'
destination_folder = 'destination'

batch_files = [
    os.path.join(working_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(working_folder)
    if any(w in f for w in ['April 16', 'April 23'])
]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in batch_files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)
    shutil.move(f, destination_folder)

print(df.head())
```